# frameタグの中に、YouTubeのビデオIDが設定されているangular式を指定して動画再生したい

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs, html5

iframeタグの中に、YouTubeのビデオIDが設定されているangular式を指定して
動画再生したいのですが、可能でしょうか。

現状、直接的にビデオIDを指定する方法が分からなかったので、
仕方なくSelectBoxを使っております。
（SelectBoxでビデオIDを選択すると、選択したIDの動画が再生出来るようになっています）
　※以下参照

これを、SelectBoxを使用せずに、直接動画を再生出来るようにすることは可能でしょうか。

色々調べて試行錯誤しましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
ご教授頂けると大変助かります。宜しくお願い致します。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html nd-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script>
        var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", [])
          .config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
            $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
              'self',
              '"https://www.youtube.com/embed/**'
            ]);
          });

        app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $sce) {
            $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
                return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + src);
            };
        })
    </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="TestController">

    <div>
        <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(url)}}"> </iframe>
    </div>

    <div>
        <select ng-model="url">
          <option>{{■YouTubeのビデオID■}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 直接動画再生出来るのがベストですが、「ボタンを押すと再生可能になる」でも良いかなと考えております。ご回答頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 「直接」とは具体的にどういった挙動を想定されているのか説明できますか？

Comment: わかりずらくてすみません。  現状はセレクトボックスを操作しないと動画が再生されませんが、ページが開いた瞬間から動画が再生できるようにしたいです。

Answer (score 0):

質問の意図を読み取れているか不安ですが、以下で期待されている挙動になりますか？

```
<div>
  <iframe ng-src="{{youtubeUrl}}"> </iframe>
</div>
```

---

```
app.controller('TestController',
['$scope', '$sce',
function($scope, $sce) {
  var id = "YouTubeのビデオID"
  $scope.youtubeUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id);
}])
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！  上記の方法だと、"YouTubeのビデオID"が固定となると思いますが、"YouTubeのビデオID"は別途JSONから取得して{{YouTubeのビデオID}}のような形で指定したいと考えております。  ですので、イメージとしては、{{youtubeUrl}} + {{YouTubeのビデオID}} のようにしたいです。    ※伝わりましたでしょうか。分かりづらい点ありましたら遠慮なくご指摘ください。  お手数ですがよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `id`は変数なのでそこをJSONから取得したビデオIDにすれば良いと思いますが...。何か問題点について認識ずれが発生しているような気がします。